# How to get the name of an element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get the name of an element in Javascript. Meaning if the element is `<div />`, then `"div"` would be returned. If it's `<img src="" />` then `"img"` would be returned. I'm using jquery to select a bunch of elements and then calling a custom function on all of them. Within that function I want to know what I'm dealing with. How do I do this?

Seems like a simple thing. And I think I've done it before but I just can't find it. Google results keep giving me "get element by name" no matter how I phrase it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [nodeName](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t20) (see [this note about tagName](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t23)):

> "My advice is not to use tagName at all.
>   nodeName contains all functionalities of tagName, plus a few more. Therefore nodeName is always the better choice."

Comment: took the words right out of my mouth, well, clicks out of my keyboard, actually...

Comment: Results can vary on `text` nodes and `attribute` nodes, but HTML elements should give the exact same result when using `tagName` and `nodeName`. So if you know that your node is an HTML element, it shouldn't really matter. Right?!

Answer (score 1):

[tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.tagName) or [nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName)

Answer (score 0):

You want `element.nodeName` Or, within jQuery:

```
$(".includeMe").each(function(){
  alert(this.nodeName);
});

<img class="includeMe" src="puppies.jpg" />
<div class="includeMe">Hello World</div>
<p   class="includeMe">Don't forget me as well</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).each(function() {
    switch (this.tagName) {
        // Handle cases
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For `element.tagName` and `element.nodeName` return the name of your tag, in uppercase.

If you want it in lowercase, just use `element.tagName.toLowerCase()` or `element.nodeName.toLowerCase()`.